# Find index of a string array

Tags: java

I have a string :

```
String str = "sces123 4096 May 27 16:22 sces123 abc";
```

I want to get `sces123 abc` from the string. My code is :

```
String[] line = str.split("\\s+");
String name = str.substring(str.indexOf(line[5]));
```

It returns the whole string.

Dont know how to do.

any help appreciated!

Comment: This happens because `sces123` is not only the fifth term of the string, but also the first.

Comment: What is the rule here ? I do not understand the logic.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be

```
String[] line = str.split("\\s+");
String name = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(line[5]));
```

because str.lastindexOf(line[5]) returns 0 and then the substring returns the whole String.

Comment: I tried it too.
I want to get all string after 16:22 .(this is the time)
The code you write will not work if string after time is sces123 sces123

Answer (score 0):

As  `Glorfindel` said in the comment `sces123` which is the content of if `line[5]` also contain as the first `substring` in the main `String str`. That why you are getting the full string.

Whats really happening here is:

```
indexOf( line[ 5 ]) --> returning 0
str.substring(0) -->  returning substring form 0 to last which is the main string
```

If you are only doing the hard codded things then i don't see the purpose of you here.

But What you want you get in this way (if it serve your purpose ) :

```
String name = str.substring( str.indexOf( line[ 5 ]+" "+line[6] ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you just need to change `str.indexOf -> str.lastIndexOf`.

Answer (score 0):

This is one easy solution :

```
String str = "sces123 4096 May 27 16:22 sces123 abc";
//split spaces
String[] line = str.split(" ");
//get 2 last columns
String name = (line[5] + " " + line[6]);
System.out.println(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) to find the end of the 5th match:

```
String str = "sces123 4096 May 27 16:22 sces123 abc";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    m.find();
}

String name = str.substring(m.end());
```

In my opinion this is better than using `lastIndexOf` on to concatenating elements at indices 5 and 6, for the following reasons:

- It does not require `line[5]` to be the last occurence of that string.

  Using `lastIndexOf` doesn't work for input

  ```
  "sces123 4096 May 27 16:22 sces123 sces123"
  ```
- It also works for seperator strings of arbirtrary length.

  Using `line[ 5 ]+" "+line[6]` doesn't work for input

  ```
  "sces123 4096 May 27 16:22 sces123             abc"
  ```
- It does not require the number elements after the `split` to be 7.

  Using `line[ 5 ]+" "+line[6]` doesn't work for input

  ```
  "sces123 4096 May 27 16:22 sces123 abc def"
  ```

Comment: He have a standar format he didnt say for another one to make your code like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```html
        String str = "sces123 4096 May 27 16:22 sces123 abc";
        String[] line = str.split("\\s+");

        System.out.println(str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(line[5])));
```

Comment: I did not check the answers, my mistake. I was trying on my eclipse. this code is working fine.